# Evaluation of boolean expressions in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm testing the `ng-show` and AngularJS expressions, but I found something I can't understand. I created a variable `displayed` and assigned a string `'false'` (not boolean) to it. The expression `displayed && true` is evaluated to true, and the second div is shown without problem (because a string and true should be true). I know there are some differences between Angular expressions and JavaScript expressions, however I don't know why the first div is not shown; it seems that the `displayed` is compiled to a boolean by Angular.

Here is the jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/micmia/1psf70tv/3/

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="displayed">test1</div>
    <div ng-show="displayed && true">test2</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.displayed = 'false';
});
```

Comment: It can be helpful to use {{displayed}} or {{expression}} generally to debug expressions.

Comment: Does `<div ng-show="!!displayed">test1</div>` behave?

Comment: @Davin Tryon - Yeah, I just tried that and it _does_ work. Super bizarre. I guess the question is, why set it to `"false"` instead of `true`? Incidentally, this appears to be only with the string "false" . . . if you change it to "banana" in the fiddle, it works fine.

Comment: `if(string)` will be truthy unless the string is empty.  This is equivalent to what you are doing with `ng-show` and using `"false"` is simply a string

Comment: @carton 'false' != false . . . Run `Boolean('false')` in your console, and you'll see that it should be true.

Comment: @DavinTryon yes it works, but I'm still confused. Why ``displayed`` is not working as a string in the first div ?

Comment: @tandrewnichols I think this directive is looking first if the value i a boolean then a string boolean then a string.

Comment: @carton Might depend on the version of angular. Looking at the current code now, it's just using a ternary expression with a truthy/falsy comparison, so `'false'` _should_ evaluate to true. https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/2a156c2d7ec825ff184480de9aac4b0d7fbd5275/src/ng/directive/ngShowHide.js#L161. @micmia Might be worth opening a bug on angular (unless you're using an older version, in which case, you might try updating).

Comment: @tandrewnichols yes you're right. I'm using AngularJS 1.2.1. This bug has been resolved in the latest stable version (1.3.15). Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's how angular evaluated the string `'false'` and `'f'` and some others as well.
There was an open [bug](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/3436) about it.

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/j39y9tvn/) works with a later version.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using string variable in ng-show or ng-hide means you can check the variable like expression shown below:

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="displayed != null">test1</div>  
    <div ng-show="displayed == 'false'">test2</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.displayed = 'false';
});
```

now both div will be shown correctly

If you are using boolean variable in ng-show or ng-hide means you can check the variable like shown below:

Template:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-show="displayed">test1</div>  
    <div ng-show="!displayed">test2</div>
</div>
```

Controller:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', []);

myApp.controller('MyCtrl', function ($scope, $parse) {
    $scope.displayed = false;
});
```

for above Boolean condition first div will not be shown and second div will be showed.

Answer (score 0):

Here I have directly passed the string as a attribute value to ng-show directive and since as per javaScript typeConversion it should evaluate to true but this is not happening here with string values(result into false),although it is working fine for numeric values.

So this is a bug in evaluating boolean expressions in angularJs.

My Code:

```
 <div ng-controller="myController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="name">
    <p>{{name}}</p>
    <p>{{10+10}}</p>
    <button type="button" ng-click="myFunction(this)">click Me !!</button>

    <p ng-show="rabbit">The name is {{ name | uppercase }}</p>

  </div>
```